# Windows forms authentication accessing maxInvalidPasswordAttempts tries left

Tags: forms-authentication

In my web config file the maxInvalidPasswordAttempts is set to 3.

I have a change password form which allows the user to enter their security answer 3 times before the account locks out.

However i was wondering if its possible to pull out the number of tries left in order to display a relevant error message when the user tries for the third time.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the number of remaining tries in a Session variable, as is done [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/custom_authentication.aspx)